# Is there any library for express or node can get automatically REST API from collections?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, automation

I use bookshelf as orm and then I write some collections base on models.

for instance the models is:

```
var Category = Bookshelf.Model.extend({

tableName: 'categories',

posts: function () {
return this.hasMany('Product');
}
});
```

module.exports = Bookshelf.model('Category', Category);

the collections is like categories.js:

```
var Base = require('./base');
var Category = require('../models/category');


var Categories = Base.Collection.extend({
model: Category
});
module.exports = Base.collection('Categories', Categories);
```

But I have many collections like this, for example 100 collections class like this.

Is there any library for express or node can get automatically REST API from collections? or some code can automatically generate the REST API like:

```
 GET  /API/category
 POST /API/category
 GET  /API/category/{id}
 PUT  /API/category/{id}
 DELETE /API/category/{id}
```

I know how to manually write REST API, but I have 100 classes need to write API, how to make it automaticall generate API?

Comment: can this help: http://loopback.io/ ?

Comment: Not sure if helpful for your case: http://sailsjs.org/features#?rest